# Error al mostrar contenido en método constructor

Tags: java, poo

Comento mi caso, estoy aprendiendo el método constructor en java, pero al escribir la instancia para mostrar el contenido me marca este error:

```
cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
```

Mi codigo:

```
package clasesypersonas;

public class Personas {

String nombre;
int edad;


public Personas(String nombre, int edad) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
}

public static void MuestraContenido() {

    System.out.println("El nombre es: " + nombre);
    System.out.println("La edad es: " + edad);
}

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Has declarado el método MuestraContenido como estático. Eso significa que no está asociado a ningún objeto, con lo que no tiene acceso a los atributos del mismo.

Deberías declararlo así:

```
public void muestraContenido() { //métodos empiezan con minúscula

    System.out.println("El nombre es: " + nombre);
    System.out.println("La edad es: " + edad);
}
```

Cuando declaras un método (o un atributo como estático significa que no pertenece a ninguna instancia, es lo más parecido a crear una función *global*. Te pongo un ejemplo algo tonto para que veas la diferencia:

```
class MiClase {

    private static int instancias=0; //contador de objetos
    private int numInstancia
    public MiClase() {
        this.numInstancia = instancias++; //aumentamos el contador
    }

    public static int getNumeroInstancias() {
        return instancias;
    }

    public int getPosicion() {
        return this.numInstancia;
    }
}

public class Main {

     public static void main(String ...args) {
         System.out.println("Número de instancias de MiClase: " +
             MiClase.getInstancias()); //mostrará 0
         MiClase mc=new MiClase();
         System.out.println("Número de instancias de MiClase: " +
             MiClase.getInstancias()); //mostrará 1
         mc.getPosicion(); // devolverá 0
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema que tienes es que al declarar tu metodo `MuestraContenido` con la palabra `static` estás diciendo que ese método "va a existir siempre".

Mientras que los atributos de tu clase no tienen por que existir.

Explicado de otra manera, puedes llamar a `MuestraContenido` sin necesidad de crear una instancia de esa clase, con lo cual java es imposible que sepa que nombre y que edad mostrar.